# Target last LI Javascript then manipulate

Tags: javascript, html

I want to target the last LI and convert this into another element.

For instance I have HTML markup as follows

```
<ol class="questions">
   <li>Element</li>
   <li>Element</li>
   <li>Element</li>
</ol>
```

But I want to make it so the last element in the list turns into a DIV then the list element closes before it

```
<ol class="questions">
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
 </ol>
   <div class="changed-div">Text</div>
```

How could I do this with javascript?

I have started to play around with code such as

```
$('</ol>'}).insertBefore('.questions li:last-child');
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's clear you're using jQuery, you can do:

```
var lastElement = $("ol.questions li:last"); //Store the last element in a variable
$('ol.questions').after('<div class = "changed-div">' + lastElement.html() + '</div>'); //Create a new div after the list with the contents of the last element
lastElement.remove(); //Delete the last element
```

Answer (score 0):

Selectors can fail sometimes, I recommend selecting the li tags like so

```
var questionArray = $('.questions').find('li');
```

This will make an array of all the li inside your ol, to get the last one

```
var lastQuestion = questionArray[questionArray.length-1];
```

Now you have the last question in a variable, Now you can extract the text and appended to whatever you want

```
var  changed-div =  $('<div/>').addClass('changed-div').append(lastQuestion.html());
$('.questions').insertAfter(changed-div);
```

and remove the li from the ol

```
lastQuestion.remove();
```

This might take a couple of more steps but give you far more control to add and remove items to the ol and the div tags